# Grep file after loaded after a particular minute

Tags: shell

Can anyone please help me in getting the command to search files loaded after a particular minute.

Example:-

I want the files loaded after the time 2017/02/15.11.
That means all the files loaded after 11

Comment: please show your eforts

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert you custom date into a recognizable date format:

```
DATE="2017/02/15.11"
TIME="${DATE##*.}:00"
DATE="${DATE%.*}"

echo "DATE: ${DATE} TIME: ${TIME}"
```

Then just pass it to find:

```
find /dir -newermt "${DATE} ${TIME}"
```